# Problems with bash script, mysql inserts and launchd

Tags: bash, mysql, launchd

I am developing a automated system, which consists of 3 parts: mysql, bash and launchd.
Bash script takes folders of work related stuff, zips, archives and puts info about them into database that is located on a local MAMP server.
Everything works as expected when I run the script from terminal. But when I use Launchd to automatically run this script, it functions without errors and it does not put the values into database.

I've tried to make logs of returned messages, but the logs end up being empty as the command has run the way it was supposed to.

Any help would be appreciated!

### .plist contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.adevo.ari.zip</string>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Volumes/Archive-Plus/B-ARCHIVE-PLUS/ZZ_UTILITY_FOLDER/Compress.sh</string>
  </array>

  <key>Nice</key>
  <integer>1</integer>

  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>120</integer>

  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

I made this .plist file just by searching the web.

As far as I understand the problem is in the launchd plist file. It somehow doesnt give the "range" to use mysql database.

Comment: check permissions for lunchd to destination file/database/called script etc. try setting SUID for lunchd executable.

Comment: I guess i did not mention that I run this script as administrator and everything this script does, it does as adminstrator

Comment: When you run this manually you run it by admin and everything works. But when it runs automatically - are you sure it is running as administrator?

Comment: Well, how exactly should I verify that? For example when the script just makes a folder, and it is run by launchd, it shows that it was made by admin.

Comment: if the program is called `launchd` then use command `watch -n1 'ps aux | grep launchd'` this will check each second for launchd program and show you the user that started the command

Comment: Does not work, I'm using mac, but I'll look for an alternative for mac.

Comment: Ok, the command is run by admin. It is not the problem.

Comment: You've mentioned "range" but it is out of context for me. could you elaborate more on this? Notice that if you pass a word 'range' to mysql it might be interpreted as part of the SQL syntax, if you think 'range' is causing problem with mysql try changing it to something else like 'rangee'

Comment: I was just trying to say that launchd could not reach mysql somehow.

Comment: 'somehow' is not enough. give a full error that it encounters. try to specify full path to mysql executable. command `whereis mysql` or `which mysql` should give you full path

Comment: Well, thats the thing when i try to make logs of error messages they are empty. Like the command did not end with error. Have you worked with launchd before?

Comment: never but in regards to logs did you tried this solution: http://serverfault.com/questions/183589/how-do-i-activate-launchd-logging-on-os-x  ?

Comment: Yes, i tried it! It does not return any errors.

Comment: Has your script (the `.sh` file, not the plist) been made executable, i.e. did you `chmod +x` it?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, variations in script or executable behavior often result from environment (PATH, etc.).  For this reason, I highly recommend using a wrapper script to configure the environment for the script or executable of interest and then use `env -i` to test execution of the wrapper.

It can also help to strip the environment before configuring any required environment variables in the wrapper script.

This is also useful for cron, Jenkins, Rundeck, and many other ways of invoking scripts or executables.

Comment: The problem is not relevant anymore.
Finaly I just used an all-time open terminal window to run a wrapper script that just run the main script every x minutes.
It's bad. I was new to this stuff.
Your answer may help me in my next endevours.